# PayPal IPN Configuration using Java Web Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on PayPal IPN Listener Configuration using Spring Web Service. I searched in the Google, I can't get much useful resource for Java Implementation there is lot of Examples for PHP only.

I am trying to create a recurring payment option for my web application using PayPal Recurring Payment APIs. I have some premium membership for my website user have to pay some money to subscribe membership. I created a Billing Plan, Billing Agreement and I used Approval URL from Billing Agreement response to get Authorize from user. I got stuck in the IPN Listener. I have no idea how to configure IPN Listener in Spring Web Service. I need to have auto renewal feature in my Web Application. Here is my listener

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ipn", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody 
    Map<String,Object> IPNListener(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", "_notify-validate")); //You need to add this parameter to tell PayPal to verify
            for (Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
                String name = e.nextElement();
                String value = request.getParameter(name);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
            }
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
            InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String result = "";
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            String rc = result.trim();
            logger.info("IPN Listener Result :: " + rc);
            if ("VERIFIED".equals(rc)) {
                logger.info("IPN Listener Verified");
                // Add Premium Membership for User
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("IPN Listener Exception ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have so many users in my Web Application. Here I don't have idea 
how to identify which user's payment is done? 
which user I need to activate the premium membership? 
Is there any way to configure membership_Id and User_Id to get back in IPN Listener while creating Billing Plan or Billing Agreement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for this problem. I used the created `Agreement_Id` to track `user_id` and `membership_id`. After I executed the Agreement, I stored `Agreement_Id` with `membership_id` and `user_id` in my database. I will get `Agreement_Id` in name of `Recurring_Payment_Id` in IPN Listener. I will query my database to get `user_id` and `membership_id` using `Agreement_id`. Hope this may help someone.

Comment: How paypal will know my server detail for IPN url ? can you please explain how to set it.

Comment: You have to setup that IPN Url in Paypal developers dashboard